# How to resolve Fatal error: Call to undefined function hash()?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, php-fpm, vbulletin

I have this error message on my website:

```
    Call to undefined function hash() on line 738 in .../public_html/dbtech/dbseo/includes/class_db.php
#0 .../public_html/dbtech/dbseo/includes/rewrite/thread.php(265): DBSEO_Database->generalQuery('\r\n\t\t\t\tSELECT *\r...', false)
#1 .../public_html/dbtech/dbseo/includes/class_core.php(2396): DBSEO_Rewrite_Thread::getInfo(Array)
#2 .../public_html/dbtech/dbseo/hooks/global_complete.php(36): DBSEO::processContent(' 
#3 .../public_html/includes/functions.php(7641) : eval()'d code(3): require('/usr/home/admin...')
#4 .../public_html/includes/functions.php(7641): eval()
#5 .../public_html/index.php(821): print_output(' #6 {main}
Fatal error: Call to undefined function hash() on line 738 in ..../dbtech/dbseo/includes/class_db.php in ..../vb/vb.php on line 286
```

log details :

```
[error] 84641#100515: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; vB_Database has a deprecated constructor in .../public_html/includes/class_core.php on line 83
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; vB_Datastore has a deprecated constructor in .../public_html/includes/class_core.php on line 1478
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; vB_Input_Cleaner has a deprecated constructor in .../public_html/includes/class_core.php on line 1819
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; vB_Registry has a deprecated constructor in .../public_html/includes/class_core.php on line 3151
PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; vB_Session has a deprecated constructor in .../public_html/includes/class_core.php on line 3539" while reading response header from upstream,request: "GET /? HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
(root@Host)-(09:44P)-(01/06)-(1)
```

I have this error message both of nginx and Apache 2.4
What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of vBulletin is out of date. Upgrade to the latest available supported point release or major version.